What is Mathematica's equivalent of Maple's package algcurves?
Maple has a package called algcurves for plane algebraic curves, providing some powerful functions. For instance, it can compute a basis for holomorphic differentials, locate all singularities, determine if a curve is hyperelliptic, and, if so, generate its Weierstrass form. Notably, it can handle the defining equations with symbolic coefficients, which is definitely within the computational scope of Mathematica. I’m wondering if Mathematica has a comparable package for working with plane algebraic curves, as I have not encountered one yet.

Compute (numeric) singular points  of f(x,y)=0 via NSolve[Resultant[f, D[f, y]] == 0, x].  There is an issue with genus.  You can search forum for details.

Some of what tou seek might be found in this book by Barry Dayton.
